# Javascript load a link with javascript variables as querystring

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to load a url with javascript which has variables as querystring parametres. Here is my code:

```
var username = params.username;
var password = params.password;

if(document.URL.indexOf("2") != -1) {
    var auto_refresh = setInterval(function () {
        var t = Date.now();
        $('#show').load('http://*******/updates/update2.php?username=username&password=password');
    }, 30000);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just try with:

```
$('#show').load('http://******/updates/update2.php?username=' + username + '&password=' + password);
```

Or with `jQuery`:

```
$('#show').load('http://*****/updates/update2.php?' + $.params({
  username: params.username,
  password: params.password
}));
```

Comment: Yes it worked! I will aprove your answer in 4 minutes. Thanks a lot.